# I want to create touch event on screen in android, as magnetic field change

Tags: android

I want to create a service which will run in background and create touch event on screen in android, as magnetic field change for my virtual reality glasses.

this my code

```
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                    magneticX.setText( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[0]));
                    magneticY.setText( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[1]));
                    magneticZ.setText( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[2]));


                    if(sensorEvent.values[0]>100){


//                      Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
//                       View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
//                       MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(time,time,0,100f ,100f, 0);
//                       v.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                        Process process = null;
                        try {

                            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input tap 100 100 ");
                            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.valMag_Msg)).setText("Magnet on Left lower corner");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                    }else{
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.valMag_Msg)).setText("Normal");;                       
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```